# Trigger dynamic set of jobs

Tags: jenkins

How do I setup a Jenkins job to trigger jobs dynamically defined in a variable/parameter?

Pseudo code for my problem:

```
def MASTER_JOB:
  for job in $downstream_jobs
     trigger $job and wait for it.

downstream_jobs_string=<list given from a script>
call MASTER_JOB
```

- The build action "Trigger/call builds on other projects" and the post-build actions "Parameterized trigger plugin" and "Build other projects" don't allow job names defined in a parameter.
- I don't seem to get the Build multi-configuration project together with the GroovyAxis plugin to work. It seems like the groovy code isn't run in the job build environment, but during the save of the job configuration.

I understand that you via a script can trigger a dynamic list of jobs via their build-start-URL:s but that seems like a more progrmatically solution which would require more adminstrive work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a perfect candidate for [Python Jenkins API](http://packages.python.org/jenkinsapi/). Heres is, for example, [a command-line interface](http://packages.python.org/jenkinsapi/jenkinsapi.command_line.html#module-jenkinsapi.command_line.jenkins_invoke) to invoke a job.

Comment: I'd hoped for a less programatic solution, as I want the Jenkins instance to be maintainable by others than me. But it's a nice approach. The Jenkins remote API is a good last resort when nothing else works;)

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use the [matrix jobs plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Project+Plugin). We had similar use case as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20409091/jenkins-parameterized-matrix-job/25997888#25997888).