# Provide userName and shortDescription in Jenkins remote API job triggering

Tags: jenkins

I know how to provide build parameters:

```
wget --post-data='json={"parameter": {"name": "testparam", "value": "HELLO"}}' http://jenkins/job/Job1/build?delay=0sec
```

But, is it possible to provide a shortDescription and userName in a Jenkins remote API build request via wget/curl?

How should it look like in json or xml? Is there any manual/guidance on the net?

I will use this in along with the problem described in [Trigger dynamic set of jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224177/trigger-dynamic-set-of-jobs). I want to provide triggered job with the calling job name and build number.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider using Jenkins CLI (http://[jenkins-host]/cli for help in the browser). You can specify a user to a **build** CLI command. I'm not sure what you mean by short description  when starting a build, though.

**Update:** Please see Jenkins Wiki [Authenticating Scripted Clients](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients). I've created a user `foobar` ('full name' `Foo Bar`) and tried the following:

```
wget --auth-no-challenge --http-user=foobar --http-password=[apiToken] http://jenkins.yourcompany.com/job/your_job/build
```

Where the token is obtained from user configuration page: `http://localhost:8081/user/foobar/configure`. It worked. The user has to exist, though. Also, you must specify `--auth-no-challenge` option, otherwise it kicks off the build as anonymous. The status description says `Started by user Foo Bar`.

**Another Update** If everything else fails, you may consider the following workaround: start *all* builds via the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) with an additional boolean parameter that tells the triggered job whether to run or not. In case the job is asked not to run it would fail immediately and call a 'clean-up' job passing to it the build info; the clean-up job then will delete the build from the system.

Comment: The short description in json/xml is saying "Started by user anonymous". I want it to tell who triggered the build as for a normal downstream job. There is looks like this: Started by upstream project "MasterJob" build number 16

Comment: The triggered job xml/json even contains upstreamBuild, upstreamProject, upstreamUrl. It would be nice to keep track of the cause to the triggering by providing info which fills those in on the triggered job.

Comment: I could execute a groovy script via the CLI and control all parts of the build, but I would like a more light-weight solution.

Comment: You have a solution to get rid of the anonymous trigger, I'll give you a point for that:) But I would like to set the trigger cause as it would when triggered by another job. I'll rephrase my question a bit.

Comment: Looks exactly like your question: http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/Set-upstream-project-when-starting-a-build-using-the-remote-API-tp4175076p4187747.html

Comment: hudson.tasks.Fingerprinter.enableFingerprintsInDependencyGraph looks really interesting! It would be a acceptable solution to tie all related projects to each other by fingerprints. Thanx! But it's not really an answer fo the original question:(

Comment: If you find a solution please post it (and ping me via a comment or something). This looks like a problem that an advanced Jenkins user must be able to know how to deal with.